# An issue with a website - some of the menu items are sending the users to random URL's

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a website, and there's a problem with the menu item links.
When you click on the menu items sometimes it's redirect you to random URL that.
I don't know what to do about it.
The website: https://klavim.org/
The URL it sending to: https://wqzyxxrrep.com/1947431/?var=klavim.org

I've tried to go over the plugins that the website's owner have, but couldn't find anything that might cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your JavaScript and Jquery errors and check bug in your js libraries. If after it showing same you can contact your hosting service provider to fix the firewall/antivirus problem of them.

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately I don't know how to fix JavaScript and Jquery errors, so I'll try contacting the hosting service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Is your WordPress website redirecting users to unknown malicious sites means your website might be hacked. 
Install some security plugins like *Wordfence* and scan your website.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/